# Moving from Subversion to Accurev

Tags: svn, accurev

I've just started a new job where they use Accurev. I've been using Subversion for years so I've been trying to find a "Subversion to Accurev" guide, but the only articles online are comparisons between the two tools (usually published by Accurev). Can anyone recommend a good manual/article/blog post/anything?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's really isn't a one-to-one compatibility chart between Accurev and Subversion because Accurev includes so many tools that are integrated into the revision control system.

The big difference between Subversion and Accurev is that Subversion almost makes you work on the same trunk/branch as everyone else while Accurev gives you a completely private space where to work called a stream. The way it works is this:

- You have a task, and create a *stream* for that task. The stream is based upon what's currently is in integration.
- You do your work on your stream. Once you've finish, you test.
- You now rebase your stream to incorporate all the changes that took place while you were doing your own work. This is called rebasing.
- You deliver your stream to the integration.

The best way of thinking about this is saying *stream* = *branch*. If you did the same in Subversion you would be:

- You create a branch for each task you're doing.
- You work on this task branch.
- When you finish and test, you merge from the trunk (or wherever you branched from) back to your branch to get any changes that happened while you were working on your branch.
- You retest, and once everything is finished, you merge your changes back from your branch back to the trunk or where ever you initially branched from.

Notice that your branch and the trunk will contain the same code both at the beginning of your task when you first branched, and at the end when you rebased and delivered (i.e. merge from trunk to branch, and then from branch back to trunk).

And please keep this in mind: You didn't die and go to Hell. Instead, you're merely working with Accurev.

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping for a guide to the basic processes, e.g. I fixed a bug today but instead of a commit I seem to have to do a Keep then a Promote. Is that correct, or have I got the wrong idea?

Comment: Keep operation is within your workspace. Unless you promote it , it wont be available to other users.

Comment: Keep = private check-in
Promote = public check-in
If you Promote a file that is modified and not Kept yet, it will explicitly Keep it to create the "real" version that gets promoted.

You can Keep file(s) in your private workspace as often as you'd like, to support iterative versioning, preserved on the server, without exposing your colleagues to your work until you're ready to deliver it to your parent stream - via a Promote.